# Consuming a click-once application from an MVC controller/action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, clickonce

I am using an MVC controller/action located in /myServer/myArea/MyClickOnce/Open that returns a FileResult

```
public class MyClickOnceController : Controller
{
   public FileResult Open()
   {
      FilePathResult file = new FilePathResult("/Provisioning/4843EA3F-9138-4A0D-9D33-BF4CDDEB7C7E/MyClickOnce.application", "application/x-ms-application");
      return file;
   }
}
```

this works fine for the initial loading, but then click-once makes a subsequent request to:
/myServer/myArea/MyClickOnce/9.0.0.132/MyClickOnce.exe.manifest

This path doesn't actually exist because the physical path for the click once is in:
/Provisioning/4843EA3F-9138-4A0D-9D33-BF4CDDEB7C7E/*

so it exists here:
/Provisioning/4843EA3F-9138-4A0D-9D33-BF4CDDEB7C7E/9.0.0.132/MyClickOnce.exe.manifest

Should I be using routing to redirect all these subsequent requests?  Is there a better approach to consume a click-once application from and MVC controller/action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a RedirectResult, the subsequent requests to the ClickOnce manifest and other files get routed to the correct directory.

```
   public ActionResult Open()
   {
      string path = "/Provisioning/4843EA3F-9138-4A0D-9D33-BF4CDDEB7C7E/MyClickOnce.application";
      return new RedirectResult(path);
   }
```